# How can simulate a join statement in a child thread that does not know who to join

Tags: c#, multithreading, join

I have three Threads:

- **main**
- **thread1**
- **thread2**

steps:

1. **main** thread start **thread1**
2. **main** thread start **thread2**
3. **thread1** should join **thread2**

How can I do this without use join/suspend and resume.

PS: the **thread1** should not know about **thread2** existence.

I did this using suspend and resume, and it works pretty well, but my boss didn't accept this solution.

piece of code just to have an idea. this is not the real code.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => Thread1Work());
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(() => Thread2Work());
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(() => StartWork(thread1, thread2));

        thread3.Start();

        if(CloseProgram())
        {
            thread2.Abort();
        }           
    }

    public static bool CloseProgram()
    {
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        while (true)
        {
            sw.Start();
            while (!EndProgram() && sw.ElapsedMilliseconds < 60000){ }

            if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > 60000)
            {
                sw.Stop();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                sw.Stop();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void StartWork(Thread thread1, Thread thread2)
    {
        thread2.Start();

        thread1.Start();

        thread2.Suspend();

        while (thread2.IsAlive) { }

        thread1.Join();

        thread2.Resume();

        while (!thread2.IsAlive) { }

        thread2.Join();
    }

    public static void Thread2Work()
    {
        while(true){ DoSomething(); }
    }

    public static bool EndProgram()
    {
        if(someThing())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void Thread1Work()
    {
        DoOtherThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should the first worker be waiting on the second worker if it shouldn't know about it at all?  Clearly it's dependent on it in some way at a conceptual level.  Also, if you're doing this it would imply that these threads are performing side effects observable by another thread.  That's usually a bad idea; try to avoid doing that.

Comment: the code is above now, sry, i had no time to post it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can change the code running on both threads.

You can pass a semaphore to both threads 1 and 2 and have thread 1 to call WaitOne while thread 2 calls Release at the end.

Comment: The DoSomething() method cannot be changed, actually i am testing its execution, thread2 must start to run, then a execute thread1, thread1  removes some system requisites that thread2 needs to work perfectly, and thread should not complete its job, that is the test.

Answer (score 0):

This can most likely be better handled using tasks.

Break the work up into discrete units, wait for both of the first units to complete, then use the ContinueWith method to effectively join the work.

Alternatively, a producer consumer pattern may be more appropriate, in which case I'd recommend looking at the BlockingCollection class to mediate communication between the threads.

However to be able to give a more detailed answer, a bit more detail in the question would be useful about what you are trying to achieve.